# Other ways to create a Bean Factory in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, factory, spring-bean

I understand the difference between a `BeanFactory` and an `ApplicationContext`.

I am also aware that a BeanFactory instance can be created from xml files, which reside in the classpath or anywhere else in the file system. So, an XMLBeanFactory instance is created in such cases.

At the same time, I was digging into `BeanFactory` documentation and stumbled upon this.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html

> Normally a BeanFactory will load bean definitions stored in a configuration source (such as an XML document), and use the org.springframework.beans package to configure the beans. However, an implementation could simply return Java objects it creates as necessary directly in Java code. There are no constraints on how the definitions could be stored: LDAP, RDBMS, XML, properties file, etc. Implementations are encouraged to support references amongst beans (Dependency Injection).

So, does this mean that the bean definition can be in non-XML format as well? viz, LDAP, RDBMS, properties file etc? If yes, please provide an snippet of it. I am exclusively looking for BeanFactory only and not any ApplicationContext implementations.

Comment: If you have a `BeanFactory` implementation for LDAP it can come from there. You can pull them from anywhere if you provide the correct implementation. Spring only provides implementation to work with propertie files, xml and java config (or groovy/ruby).

Comment: @M.Deinum When you say properties file, are you referring to spring boot application.properties?

Comment: @M.Deinum are there other implementations of BeanFactory apart from Spring framework itself?

Comment: Any property file which contains the correct format (not the `application.properties` from Spring Boot that is a regular property file containing configuration parameters.

Comment: I wrote one for JDBC a very long time ago. I suggest Google for different implementations than the ones provided by Spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'd be interested in this bean creation from property file. Please provide an example

Comment: https://deinum.biz/2018-04-12-on-spring-applicationcontext-and-bean-creation/

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for the example. Also, I understand that this is an ApplicationContext. I was curious to know if an exclusive BeanFactory instance can be created using any way other than the .xml files, in Spring, using its own implementations.

Comment: Read the blog. Also an `ApplicationContext` is a `BeanFactory`. In the sample using properties you could use the `DefaultListableBeanFactory` instead of the `GenericApplicationContext` and achieve the exact same result.

Comment: @M.Deinum I will try that out. Thank you for all the inputs.

Comment: @M.Deinum Please provide this as a reply so that I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to load an `ApplicationContext` which is a `BeanFactory` on steriods is explained in [this blog](https://deinum.biz/2018-04-12-on-spring-applicationcontext-and-bean-creation/).

```java
public class SpringContextsApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    GenericApplicationContext contextFromProperties =
      new GenericApplicationContext();

    BeanDefinitionReader reader =
      new PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader(contextFromProperties);
    reader.loadBeanDefinitions("classpath:application-context.properties");
    contextFromProperties.refresh();

    doGreeting(contextFromProperties);

    contextFromProperties.stop();
  }

  private static void doGreeting(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    Greeter greeter = ctx.getBean(Greeter.class);
    Person person = ctx.getBean(Person.class);
    greeter.greet(person);
  }
}
```

Where there is a `GenericApplicationContext` one could also use a `DefaultListableBeanFactory` instead and achieve the same result.

```java
public class SpringContextsApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    GenericApplicationContext contextFromProperties =
      new DefaultListableBeanFactory();

    BeanDefinitionReader reader =
      new PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader(contextFromProperties);
    reader.loadBeanDefinitions("classpath:application-context.properties");

    doGreeting(contextFromProperties);

    contextFromProperties.stop();
  }

  private static void doGreeting(BeanFactory ctx) {
    Greeter greeter = ctx.getBean(Greeter.class);
    Person person = ctx.getBean(Person.class);
    greeter.greet(person);
  }
}
```

To load bean definitions one needs a `BeanDefinitionReader` for that specific implementation you want to use. Here that is property files but you could write a `BeanDefinitionReader` for LDAP, JDBC, YAML etc. as well.

Spring supports out-of-the-box

- [XML](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanDefinitionReader.html)
- [Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/PropertiesBeanDefinitionReader.html) (Deprecated as of Spring 5.3, propably removed in Spring 6)
- [Groovy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/groovy/GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.html)
- [Java Classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.html)
- [JDBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcBeanDefinitionReader.html) (Purely as an exampled, deprecated in 5.3 and removed in Spring 6)

However you can create whatever implementation you like if you need.